# Chrome not displaying HTML block correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass

I'm trying to get my head around a Chrome issue. The following code works fine in FF and IE, but in Chrome I get some weirdness (Chrome is on the right, FYI);

[image]

The **SCSS** code is:

```
#contactSuggestWrapper {
  background: #eee;
  background: rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100000;
}
#contactSuggestInner {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #C4DF9B;
  padding: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 430px;
  z-index: 100001;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#contactSuggestInner h3 {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#contactSuggestInner #textarea-and-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: green;
}

#moreSuggestions {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
#moreSuggestions .lead-link-simple {
  border: 1px solid #C4DF9B;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #C4DF9B;
  padding: .25rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  margin-right: .25rem;
}
```

Some sample **HTML**:

```
<div id="textarea-and-button">
        dfsdfsfs<br>
        dfsdfsfs<br>
        dfsdfsfs<br>
    </div>

    <div id="moreSuggestions" style="background:orange">
        <div class="lead-link-simple">
            bla
        </div>
        <div class="lead-link-simple">
            bla
        </div>
        <div class="lead-link-simple">
            bla
        </div>
        <div class="lead-link-simple">
            bla
        </div>
    </div>
```

Interestingly, if I remove the *.lead-link-simple* so there are only 3 of them:

```
<div id="moreSuggestions" style="background:orange">
    <div class="lead-link-simple">
        bla
    </div>
    <div class="lead-link-simple">
        bla
    </div>
    <div class="lead-link-simple">
        bla
    </div>
</div>
```

So the issue seems to be around the fact its going onto another row :/

I've been fiddling around with the code for a while now, but I just can't figure out whats going on. Maybe a 2nd pair of eyes could? :)

Here is a demo of the problem: http://ultranerds.co.uk/bug/test.html , and then when I remove the contents from `#moreSuggestions`, it looks better:

http://ultranerds.co.uk/bug/test3.html

BTW - I tried setting up a fiddle for this, but for some reason it wasn't rendering the SCSS (even though it was selected)

Comment: Did you use any ``reset`` or  ``normalize``??

Comment: do you have live demo or something ?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I don't believe so - its using PureCSS as the base ( https://purecss.io/base/ )

Comment: @SupunPraneeth let me see if I can knock up a live demo :)

Comment: Live demo will help a lot

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO - I've just stuck a demo up (see OP near bottom, as there are 2)

Comment: Edit your question to make a live sample using the snippet edit so we can see/try it right here with the smallest possible sample code that reproduces the issue. i.e. put the rendered CSS up with the rendered HTML

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I've trimmed it down to the basics. http://ultranerds.co.uk/bug/test.html , and then a working on http://ultranerds.co.uk/bug/test3.html . the working one, the issue seems to be that it only goes onto 1 row. If you add another div into that block, it then goes weird and breaks the formatting,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The main problem**

You only specify "display: flex;" and "flex-direction" but not "flex-shrink", "flex-grow" etc. A.k.a. "What to do if the given space is not enough or too much".

Some browsers interpret those missing attributes different.

**An easy solution**

Just add "flex-shrink: 0;" to "#textarea-and-button". Et voila! It will not shrink below content-height anymore.

```
#contactSuggestInner #textarea-and-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: you legend! I was just about to post an answer saying that adding `min-height: 75px;` to that div worked (not an ideal solution, but would have worked). Your answer is much better though, and cleaner. Thanks :)